# Getting started with OpenCL with intel HD graphics in WIndows 7

Tags: graphics, opencl, intel

I found [this link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/opencl-drivers) with drivers and runtimes.

And also as per [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-opencl) , OpenCL codebuilder is now part of INDE/Media server Studio and these are not free (Though they come with trial version)

So my ultimate question is how to get started with OpenCL with Intel HD Graphics?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a starter edition of the Intel INDE suite, which is free (and is not just a trial). This contains their core OpenCL SDK. The Media Server Studio may contain some additional tools to aid OpenCL development on Intel HD Graphics, but is certainly not required in order to develop or run OpenCL programs.

You don't actually need any OpenCL SDK to get started with OpenCL development. You need a driver/runtime in order to run OpenCL programs (these are freely available, as per your first link). To develop OpenCL programs you just need the headers and a library to link against, which are both also freely available (more info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146152/do-i-really-need-an-opencl-sdk/29146331#29146331)).

Comment: considering second part of your answer: is installing the SDK the only way to get header and lib/dll or I can get it without installing SDK?

Comment: @banguru The SDKs do provide the headers and lib, but you can also download the headers directly from the Khronos website: https://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/ This website also has the sources for 1.2 version of the OpenCL library that you need to link against.

Answer (score 0):

Which programming language would you like to use? In Java you can start with a simple Java SE application and integrate the [JavaCL](https://code.google.com/p/javacl/) package. You do not need any further vendor specific drivers.

Comment: I am planning in C/C++