# CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE on casting int to float

Tags: opencl

I can't seem to find any good info anywhere for what I've run into.  I've written a bit of code for Kohonen SOM in OpenCL, on a iMac w/ a ATI Radeon HD 6770M.  I'm choosing the GPU device for the context.  There is a single line in my code that is causing a `CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE` error. If I comment it out, code compiles fine... but with it, and the variations I've tried, I consistently get the error.

Here's the code, with the offending line commented:

> "// THIS line, only, causes CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE !!!".

I'm hoping one of you guys has run into this at some point, as I'm a little baffled. `convert_float(diff)` did not work for me.

There are bound to be computational errors, as I haven't gotten beyond the essential complete-compile step, so feel free to ignore or point those out.  Either way, I'm really just trying to get beyond the compile.

```c
inline float _calc_sample_distance(__global float* weights, ulong startIdx, uint nodeWidth, __constant float* sample) {
    float accum = 0.0f;
    float diff = 0.0f;
    uint i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i<nodeWidth; i++) {
        diff = weights[startIdx+i] - sample[i];
        accum += pow(diff,2);
    }
    accum = pow(accum, .5f);
    return accum;
}

inline void _calc_coords(uint dimCount, __constant uint* dimSizes, size_t offset, uint* thisCoords) {
    // reversed so, processed as xy, then y
    ulong trim = offset, multi = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for(i = dimCount-1; i>=0; i--) {
        multi = 1;
        for(j=i-1; j>=0; j--) {
            multi *= dimSizes[j];
        }
        thisCoords[i] = trim / multi;
        trim = trim % multi; 
    } 
}

inline float _calc_map_coord_distance(uint dimCount, __constant uint* bmuCoords, uint* thisCoords) {
    float accum = 0.0f;
    uint i = 0;
    int diff = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < dimCount; i++) {
        diff = bmuCoords[i] - thisCoords[i];
        diff *= diff; 
        accum += (float)diff; // THIS line, only, causes CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE !!!
    }
    accum = pow(accum,.5f);
    return accum;
}

__kernel void calc_kohonen_som_distances(
        // map data
        __global float* weights,      // weights
        uint nodeWidth,               // the number of weights per node
        uint nodeCount,               // the total number of weights
        __constant float* sample,     // sample, of nodeWidth wide
        __global float* output        // the output distance of each node to the sample
    ) {
    size_t nodeIndex = get_global_id(0);
    ulong startIdx = nodeIndex * nodeWidth;
    output[nodeIndex] = _calc_sample_distance(weights,startIdx,nodeWidth,sample);
}

__kernel void calc_kohonen_som_update_weights(
        // map data
        __global float* weights,       // weights
        uint nodeWidth,                // the number of weights per node
        uint dimCount,                 // the number of dimensions
        __constant uint* dimSizes,     // the size of each dimension
        __constant float *sampleData,  // the sample to use for updating the bmu and surrounding units
        __constant uint* bmuCoords,    // the coordinates of the best matching unit, from which we derive offset
        float learningRate,            // calculated on the CPU as per step
        float radius                   // calculated on the CPU as per step
    ) {
    size_t nodeIndex = get_global_id(0);
    ulong startIdx = nodeIndex * nodeWidth;

    uint* thisCoords = (uint*)malloc(sizeof(uint)*dimCount);
    memset(thisCoords,0,sizeof(uint)*dimCount);

    // determine the coordinates of the offset provided
    if(dimCount!=1) {
        _calc_coords(dimCount,dimSizes,nodeIndex,thisCoords);
    } else {
        thisCoords[0] = nodeIndex;
    }

    float distance = _calc_map_coord_distance(dimCount, bmuCoords, thisCoords);
    if(distance<radius) {
        float influence = exp( (-1*distance)/(2*pow(radius,2.0f)) );
        for(uint i=0;i<dimCount;i++) {
            weights[startIdx+i] = weights[startIdx+i] + ( influence * learningRate * (sampleData[i] - weights[startIdx+i]) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Yeah, I realize it's supposed to be unnecessary, I just keep on running into this error for a variety of things that should be perfectly legal c99...not with the CPU device, just the GPU.  I am using the OpenCL.framework provided by Apple.  I have not tried downloading AMD's, as I assumed that Apple's would support it's own hardware.  I'll definitely be giving that a shot.  Thanks!  [edit] for instance, I had to provide the initial declaration for my loop variable prior to using in the for loop...that took a bit to diagnose.

Comment: That the decl inside the for loop in calc_kohonen_som_update_weights worked, while the others caused the CL_DEVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE is also a mystery to me.  I thought that one might have had something to do with the other functions being inlined, but I've tried both inline and non-inline for those functions, with the same effect.  Still, the cast to float is the blocking issue.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not finding anything from AMD for Mac OS X on AMD's site...I think all I have available is that which came with the OS.  [edit] a sad state of affairs: http://preta3d.com/os-x-users-unite/

Comment: [Build the OpenCL library file yourself and copy the includes from Khronos](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146152/do-i-really-need-an-opencl-sdk/29146331#29146331).

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion, but I think the issue is actually with ATI's compiler.  When I switch the CPU, everything works just fine.  For the time being, I'll just do that.  I also do not run into issues on NVIDIA's hardware (via AWS)...just with my iMac's ATI.  I just don't think a different library will make the difference.  Have I missed something?  Totally possible.